# PyCharm unable to identify inherited class' attributes

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, pycharm, python-typing

There's a base data class as follows:

```
class BaseClass:
  def __init__(self, attribute_1: Any):
    self.attribute_1 = attribute_1
```

There's an inherited data class using the above class as base class:

```
class DataClass(BaseClass):
  def __init__(self, attribute_1: Any, attribute_2: Dict[str, str], attribute_3: List[str]):
    super().__init__(attribute_1)
    self.attribute_2 = attribute_2
    self.attribute_3 = attribute_3
```

There's another BaseClass which expects an instance of BaseClass to work as follows:

```
class BaseActionClass:
  def __init__(self, attribute_a1: BaseClass, attribute_a2: Dict[str, str])
    self.attribute_a1 = attribute_a1
    self.attribute_a2 = attribute_a2
  
  def do_action_one(self):
    pass
  
  def do_action_two(self):
    pass
```

There's an ActionClass which uses this BaseActionClass to perform some actions:

```
class ActionClass(BaseActionClass):
  def __init__(self, attribute_a1: DataClass, attribute_a2: Dict[str, str]):
    super().__init__(attribute_a1, attribute_a2)
  
  def do_action_one(self):
    do_statement_1
    x = self.attribute_a1.attribute_1
    y = self.attribute_a1.attribute_2
  
  def do_action_two(self):
    do_something
```

In ActionClass.do_action_one, when writing y = self.attribute_a1.attribute_2, PyCharm shows a typing error of `Unresolved attribute reference 'attribute_2' for class 'BaseClass'`. How to resolve this typing error which is shown by the IDE, and why would this happen since DataClass is already inheriting from BaseClass?

Comment: I think maybe you need a primer on [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) in python? it should simplify your logic above a great deal.

Comment: Btw, the above classes are *not* data classes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem now is that `ActionClass.attribute_a1` is still `BaseClass`, because its base was declared so. It is absolutely fine, because in `ActionClass` you do not enforce `attribute_a1` to be `DataClass`, but only limit `__init__` method to it. Were it another method (not `__init__`, but, say, `set_attribute_a1` - let's forget about properties for now), you would also violate LSP this way.

I can suggest two ways to go:

### Generic

I'd assume `BaseClass` and `DataClass` definitions as yours. Then the following will work:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

_T = TypeVar('_T', bound=BaseClass)

class BaseActionClass(Generic[_T]):
  def __init__(self, attribute_a1: _T, attribute_a2: dict[str, str]) -> None:
    self.attribute_a1: _T = attribute_a1
    self.attribute_a2 = attribute_a2
  
  def do_action_one(self) -> None:
    pass

class ActionClass(BaseActionClass[DataClass]):
  # Note you don't even need to override __init__ now, it follows from generic defn
  def do_action_one(self) -> None:
    self.attribute_a1.attribute_1
    self.attribute_a1.attribute_2
```

### Direct

```py
class BaseActionClass:
  def __init__(self, attribute_a1: BaseClass, attribute_a2: dict[str, str])
    self.attribute_a1 = attribute_a1
    self.attribute_a2 = attribute_a2
  
  def do_action_one(self):
    pass
  
  def do_action_two(self):
    pass

class ActionClass(BaseActionClass):
  attribute_1: DataClass

  def __init__(self, attribute_a1: DataClass, attribute_a2: dict[str, str]):
    super().__init__(attribute_a1, attribute_a2)
  
  def do_action_one(self):
    self.attribute_a1.attribute_1
    self.attribute_a1.attribute_2
```

The former solution is preferred, because it reveals your intention initially and is more semantically correct. It means roughly the following: class `BaseActionClass` has `attribute_a1` parameter of type `_T`, which can be substituted by any `BaseClass` subclass (including `BaseClass` itself). When you subclass `BaseActionClass[DataClass]`, you enforce `_T` substitution with `DataClass`. You can still do `BaseActionClass(BaseClass(), {})` and `_T` will be `BaseClass`, but `ActionClass(BaseClass(), {})` is rejected now.

The latter solution is much less elegant. I'd advice to use it only if you don't have access to modify `BaseActionClass` (for example, it is 3rd-party module and you don't want/can't create a PR to it).